# LinkedIn bot. Search profile for keywords and export to word

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I was thinking about a way to sort of automate my job/have to look through less LinkedIn profiles.

So here is my question. Would it be possible to write a program that would search LinkedIn for you with your "keywords" and have to program automatically click through the profiles, then when it clicks a profile search for each individual keyword and keep count, then export the amount of times the keywords are mentioned to a word document, then go back and do that to each profile. I have no ides what language could do this though and I only have a highschool class worth of Javascript so I would be teaching myself how to do this. I could run this program and night and come back in the morning and be able to look through the best profiles and waste less time looking though ones where people do not have the experience they say they do.

Basically it would go:

- Execute search
- click first profile
- find total number of keywords
- export to word
- click back or return to results button
- next profile
- *repeat for, say, 300 profiles.*

I don't know how feasible this would be to figure out how to write or if its even really possible. Thanks for the helpful replies!

I got some help on reddit, and the replier said that it would probably be easiest in Ruby/RubyGems?

Comment: Hey, Robert, this is an interesting question, but will probably end up being a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. [The FAQ shares a few more details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), but in general, you can get answers to *specific* programming questions here, while very broad questions like this one are likely to be closed as off topic.

Comment: I thought it would be okay because I was asking how to do something that wasn't short and had a long answer? Anyway I could change my question to keep it up?

Comment: The problem is your actual question: the answer to “Would it be possible to write a program to…” will almost always be “yes!”, but how much effort, difficulty, time, and resources that are required vary greatly. If you can create an [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_method) for it, [your computer can do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry about that:/

Comment: So if I asked "How to create an algorithm to do this this and this" it would be okay?

Comment: @Sebastian, not unless it were much narrower than this question.  The best thing to do is roll your sleeves up and start writing code to do _something_.  Don't do the whole task, but do a piece of it: Programatically log into linked in, for example.  These little _spikes_ are what programmers to do learn what's feasible, and to compare different methods of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would probably be to use a process called "scraping"; You extract the html from the page and sort through it for useful information.

Programming languages are like religons; different people say different languages are the best. For parsing html most people (not all) would agree a high-level language like Ruby or Python would be best. However, you did specify ruby, so start by installing it.

After installing ruby (see [here](http://www.rubyinstaller.org/)), run `gem install nokogiri`

You can look for general guides on nokogiri [here](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials). Start by looking at the source code and seeing where the interesting information is (eg. links to the profiles on the search page). 300 profiles should be no problem. However, when you are testing make sure you only try 3 or 4 profiles at a time. A program requesting 300 pages being run many times may get noticed, but a one-time run should be fine (no guarantees).

Also, I would *not* recomend exporting to word. You can scan the raw text for keywords and it will be much faster.

As a final note, this will take a long time. From what it sounds like you haven't programmed much before (although previous experience in javascript will help). A lot of your time will most likely be spent reading through tutorials and searching your problem on google. Feel free to come back here when you have specific problems, and good luck!